# Redirect to another page using information from previous - JS

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

How can I redirect to another page using the information I have received as response in JS.
I am working on a authentication and authorization project using JS and PHP.

I have a `myprofile.html` which cannot be accessed unless user is logged in.

Here is the javascript code associated with `myprofile.html`

```
import {fetchGet} from "./common.js";

window.onload = (event) => {
    const headers = {
        "Authorization":`Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")}`
    }
    //fetchGet is a custom defined function accepts url and headers
    fetchGet("/guvi internship/dist/scripts/php/myprofile.php",headers).then(res=>{
        return res.json();
    }).then(data=>{
        if(data.code>=200 && data.code<=299){
            console.log(data);
        }else{
            window.location.replace("/guvi internship/dist/html/signin.html");
        }
    })
    .catch(e=>console.error(e));
};
```

Here as soon as myprofile.html loads I send a request to `myprofile.php` along with the accessToken if logged-in. If not logged in the **Authorization** header will be empty.

Here in `myprofile.php`

```
    <?php
    require_once "../../../vendor/autoload.php";
    use service\UserService;
    use exception\UnauthorizedException;
    $userService = new UserService();

    $headers = getallheaders();
    try{
        if(!isset($headers['Authorization'])){
            throw new UnauthorizedException("You need to be logged in",401);
        }
    }
    catch(UnauthorizedException $e){
        $err = $e->getError();
        http_response_code($err['code']);
        echo json_encode($err);
    }
?>
```

If the user is not logged in and tries to access `myprofile.html` he will be granted with a `401 unauthorized` error.
Now I must redirect the user to the login page but I want to chain the unauthorized response received to the `signin.html`.

I tried to achieve this using `window.location.replace("/guvi internship/dist/html/signin.html");`.
But I am not able to figure out how I can send the **unauthorized response** to `signin.html` as well

Comment: There's nothing super secure in `myprofile.html`, is there? Because disabling JS would grant immediate access to it. Is there a reason that you are using `.html` files in the first place, when you already have `.php` available?

Comment: Here is nothing private. it is public with the logged in user's information.
I am new to PHP, just wanted to know if there is a way I can acheive this using javascript.
I could just use myprofile.php to check if user is logged in as well as render HTML if logged in or redirect.Just wanted to know if I can do that by decoupling PHP and HTML @ChrisHaas

Comment: You can send the response via get parameters in the url: window.location.replace("/guvi internship/dist/html/signin.html?response="+data);.